# How many nodes do I need in a Quorum Private Blockchain?

Tags: quorum, azure

I want to deploy a private blockchain using Quorum on Azure, create some ERC721 Tokens and send them various accounts inside the Private Blockchain.

How many nodes do I need for a Private Blockchain like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are developing, then a single node is enough to get you going. A proper Quorum chain should consist of 3, or 5, or 7 nodes to start with depending on the fault tolerance you would like. Our own example spawns 7 node chain for you to use and it is pre-configured for local or docker deployment. Get it here: https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum-examples